# Why doesn't the use statement work in Rust in certain cases?

Tags: rust

I have been suffering while trying to get Rust's `use` statements to work.

All I did was copy [some code](https://github.com/johannhof/difference.rs/blob/master/examples/github-style.rs) I found, change it for my needs and be done with it, but for whatever reason, the code I copied doesn't work when added into my test code!

This is the code I want to use:

```
use difference::{Difference, Changeset};
let Changeset { diffs, .. } = Changeset::new(text1, text2, "\n");
```

I added `extern crate difference;` to the top of this file, and `difference = "0.4"` to my toml file, so I was pretty sure it would work!

But nope... I get this error:

```
 use difference::{Difference, Changeset};
                  ^^^^^^^^^^ Did you mean `self::difference`?
```

I certainly meant `Difference` as the original code seemed to work!!

To test this a bit more, I wrote this instead:

```
println!("{:?}", &difference::Difference::Add("hi".to_string()));
```

And that worked... so I figured I would just `use` `Add`:

```
use difference::Difference::Add;
println!("{:?}", &Add("hi".to_string()));
```

And that did not work at all.

```
 use difference::Difference::Add;
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Did you mean `self::difference::Difference`?
```

That feels like a practical joke... so, now Rust all of a sudden knows about `Difference`!?!?

What exactly am I doing wrong? How can I just `use` something confidently and understand it (I've read [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch07-03-importing-names-with-use.html)'s relevant part ten times, didn't help)? Why are my assumptions so wrong that this feels like Rust is playing on me and I am on the verge of getting insane?

Comment: You are inside of a module. Idiomatically, `extern crate` lines goes at the crate root.

Comment: As a learner of Rust, how can I know what the idiomatic way is? I didn't see that either in the Rust Book or in Rust By Example. Really frustrating.

Comment: I don't think anyone expects you to magically know everything; you learn things the same as the rest of us. [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch07-02-controlling-visibility-with-pub.html) has this to say: *Also note that even if we’re using an external crate within a submodule of our project, the extern crate should go in our root module (so in src/main.rs or src/lib.rs). Then, in our submodules, we can refer to items from external crates as if the items are top-level modules*

Comment: This link is to the second edition of the book, which does not seem to be the official one yet, right? I've learnt many languages before (C++, Java, Prolog, JS, Groovy, Haskell, Ceylon, Kotlin, TypeScript) and only with Rust do I have these infuriating issues with things that should just work and don't. I will persist because the only alternative I can see, C++, is even worse :) but these really basic things like "use" should just be documented more clearly (the 2nd edition seems to do that, great). Rust is nice, don't get me wrong, just feeling like stumbling the whole time right now.

Comment: [The book index suggests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/): *The second edition is a complete re-write. It is still under construction, though it is far enough along to learn most of Rust. We suggest reading the second edition and then checking out the first edition later to pick up some of the more esoteric parts of the language.*

Comment: FWIW, many people have issues with the module system and there have been multiple proposals to change it. I'm in the group that accepts the current system, so I don't have a great sense of the problems and whether or not any of the proposals improve the issues people have. *only with Rust do I have these infuriating issues with things that should just work and don't* — I doubt this is one of those cases, but the concept of something "should be working but isn't" is often a great signal that something is fundamentally wrong with our understanding. Rust's lifetimes are a good example.